# Eclipse with android NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, eclipse

I have tried everything to get this to work and now I have this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Activity

There is another post on here that says to try this in the manifesto:

uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

This solution does not work for me.

As background, I am running one windowsXP, I had to change the Bootstrap Entries to JRE System Library and JUnit3 to fix another error. I also had to change the path for the emulator to run as well.

This is my first time trying to run the droid app stuff on here. I am using the hello world example. I assume I must run the emulator for the phone first then run my code?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="edu.rit.cs.ats"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".AndroidTestActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: you do not have to start the emulator first. when you launch an android app in eclipse it will automatically open a new emulator(unless you specify manual launch in run config)

Comment: It would help to see how your activity is defined in the manifest - can you paste your manifest in here?

Comment: I will post the manifest, update my code? I did update Eclipse, if that's what you mean?